# Nested router doesn't return next callback with value of 'route'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm building out a handler for middleware and I discovered that when you return the `route` string as an argument for the `next` callback it's value is `null`.

Here's the example:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var router = express.Router()
  router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return next('route')
  })
  return router(req, res, function (nextValue) {
    console.log('// value of next')
    console.log(nextValue)
    return next(nextValue)
  })
})

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('hi')
})

module.exports = app
```

Which means you can't just pass the next handler in like this:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var router = express.Router()
  router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return next('route')
  })
  return router(req, res, next)
})
```

I know this looks very redundant because you can just do this:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
   return next('route')
})
```

However I am building a library that needs to use nested middleware in this fashion. It seems that my only option is to use a different string because If I do this:

```
  router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return next('anystring')
  })
```

The `next` callback does provide `nextValue` with `anystring`.

Why does the string `route` not propagate through nested middleware?

This seems like it actually makes sense for express to not return `route` because at that point route that route is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off [`.use` doesn't support `next('route')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419034/nextroute-doesnt-work-with-use). So I used `.all` instead. Even that doesn't return the string "route". So I needed to inject some middleware into the router at the end. If the value of `nextRoute` is not updated, then `next('route')` was called sometime during the middleware stack and I can propagate it upward to the parent middleware.

I found that I'd have to inject a piece of middleware into the end to

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var router = express.Router()
  var nextRoute = true
  router.all('/', [
    function (req, res, next) {
      return next('route')
    },
    function (req, res, next) {
      nextRoute = false
      return res.send('hi')
    },
  ])
  return router(req, res, function (nextValue) {
    if (nextRoute && !nextValue) return next('route')
    return next(nextValue)
  })
})

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('hi')
})
```

This allows for my `middleware-nest` module to work:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var express = require('express')

/** Allow for middleware to run from within middleware. */
function main (req, res, next, Router, middleware) {
  var args = _.values(arguments)
  middleware = _.flatten([_.slice(args, 4)])
  Router = (Router) ? Router : express.Router
  var router = Router()
  var nextRoute = true
  middleware.push(function (req, res, next) {
    nextRoute = false
    return next()
  })
  router.all('*', middleware)
  return router(req, res, function (nextValue) {
    if (nextRoute && !nextValue) return next('route')
    return next(nextValue)
  })
}

main.applyRouter = function (Router) {
  Router = (Router) ? Router : express.Router
  return function () {
    var args = _.values(arguments)
    args.splice(3, 0, Router)
    return main.apply(null, args)
  }
}

module.exports = main
```