# "next('route')" doesn't work with ".use()"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Am I doing something wrong here, or does express just not support `next('route')` with `.use()`?

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use([
  function (req, res, next) {
    return next('route')
  },
  function (req, res, next) {
    return res.send('sigma')
  },
])

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('alpha')
})

module.exports = app
```

This serves the string `sigma` and should server the string `alpha`.

Update: just tried this and it didn't work as well.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use('/', [
  function (req, res, next) {
    return next('route')
  },
  function (req, res, next) {
    return res.send('sigma')
  },
])

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('alpha')
})

module.exports = app
```

Update, this too:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return next('route')
},
function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('sigma')
})

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('alpha')
})

module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the discussion in [node issue #2591](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2591): since `app.use()` defines middleware, and not a "route", `next('route')` is meaningless when used with `app.use()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can tell between .all and .use is that .use defaults the path to `/`.

So this works:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.all('/', [
  function (req, res, next) {
    return next('route')
  },
  function (req, res, next) {
    return res.send('sigma')
  },
])

app.all('/', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('alpha')
})

module.exports = app
```